# No matching files (Ext.ux.AccordionList) while creating build for sencha app

Tags: sencha-touch-2, accordion

I used Accordian in my sencha app. So in view I required it as follows.

```
    requires: [
        'Ext.ux.AccordionList'
    ]
```

By using command "sencha app build production" I am trying to create a build. But it gives me following error :
[ERR] C2008: Requirement had no matching files (Ext.ux.AccordionList) 
So my build failed. Can any one help me for how I can resolve that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, I used that but it also not works for me. Then I create AccordianList through controller and It works. I create it as follows.

```
initializeView:function(){
    accordian = Ext.create('Ext.ux.AccordionList', {
        xtype: 'accordionlist',
        store: Ext.create('My_app.store.Profile.FilterTask'),
        itemId: 'task',
        singleMode: true,
        animation: true,
        animationDuration: 300,
        width: 335,
        height: 500,
        cls: 'filterOptions',
        listeners: {
            initialize: function() {
                this.load();
            }
        }
    });
    this.getMain().add(accordian);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the source for the `AccordionList` somewhere in your app?  This is not a part of the standard Sencha Touch library.  Wherever you include the file, you will then need to use `Ext.Loader.setPath` to point the loader in the right direction.

So, if you save the file in `app/ux/AccordionList.js`, use this line to include it:

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'app/ux');
```

Comment: Thanks, I used that but it also not works for me. Then I create AccordianList through controller and It works. I create it as follows.